# How to subscribe for "user enter command to prompt" event in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to implement **incremental history log** of commands which I enter to powershell. I found a lot of related questions about same history-save on-exit. Solution is here

```
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier powershell.exiting -SupportEvent -Action { Save-History }
```

I found it inconvenient, because it doesn't work for multiply tabs/ps instances. What I want is call Save-HistoryIncremental which append to existing csv file history.

But I don't know how to make callback to this function immediately after user enter command.

**Workaround:**
Closest workaround which I have right now is alter prompt:

```
Rename-Item Function:\prompt oldprompt
function prompt {
    Save-HistoryIncremental
    oldprompt
}
```

Here behavior is oposit: it save history after execution oh command (and duplicate last record on start).

Comment: JFYI, here is proof-of-concept repository https://github.com/vors/pshistory

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking completely, but does this help?

http://jaworskiblog.com/2011/08/05/logging-all-powershell-commands-and-output/

Basically, you add a "Start-Transcript" to your powershell profile.
That will log everything you do even across multiple powershell instances, I think...

Comment: 1) It create transcript for you session(s). So you can search, etc. But I looking for incremental way to preserve history across sessions. So I can type something like "#cp<Ctrl+Space>" and find a copy record with some long paths. 2) It doesn't work in powershell_ise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032075/powershell-start-transcript-this-host-does-not-support-transcription